# What is E-DEATH based on in Sense8?

Tags: realism, sense8

In Sense8 S02E05 "[Fear Never Fixed Anything](http://sense8.wikia.com/wiki/Fear_Never_Fixed_Anything)", Bug helps Naomi have (apparently all?) traces of her identity removed, such that the authorities no longer have warrants for her, with the help of a hacker behind an Anonymous-like mask.

Is e-death inspired by an existing program such as [WITSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Federal_Witness_Protection_Program)? What comes closest to it, and how can it even work, given that redaction of all personal information would amount to being [wrongly declared dead](http://money.cnn.com/2011/08/17/pf/social_security_deaths_mistakes/index.htm), which leads to a host of problems, as opposed to getting a new identity.